# How to paste data into Excel?

Tags: ruby, vba, selenium-webdriver

I am automating my application using Selenium Webdriver (Ruby). Can anyone tell me how to paste clipboard contents to a cell in Excel?

Thanks !

Comment: are you talking about a running Excel GUI? In which case I don't know, but I was going to say to use the `spreadsheet` gem.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was able to get this done using VBA commands. Using the commands  obj.Activesheet.Paste

Answer (score 1):

seems RubyXL does both, read AND write https://github.com/gilt/rubyXL haven't used it yet though..